# Jacoco Showing Wrong Coverage check Result

Tags: java, unit-testing, jacoco-maven-plugin, test-coverage

I have configure My Jacoco plugin In my project via maven.

Here is my jacoco configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
      </exclude>**/some/package/SomeClass*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>report</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>jacoco-check</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <rule>
              <element>CLASS</element>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>*Test</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <limits>
                <limit>
                  <counter>LINE</counter>
                  <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                  <minimum>80%</minimum>
                </limit>
              </limits>
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

[image: Screenshot]

I have executed the Test, and shows 94% coverage for an Abstract Class , I tested this abstract class using it's concrete Implementation.

When i run by maven build

I'm getting following error

> Rule violated for class
>   my.package.AbstractParser.1:
>   lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.80

I tried to test abstract class using a dummy implementation on Test still I'm getting the same error

Can some one tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

EDIT:
I found out the cause for failure

I have written an inline map initialization

```
return new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
      put(input, "");
    }
  };
```

And the coverage was showing 0% against this part . so my test was not covering this part.

But I tired

```
 final Map<String, String> defaultMap = new HashMap<>();
  defaultMap.put(input, "");
  return defaultMap;
```

The build pass without even coverage around new code. can some one explain me why it happened with inline initialization ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration

```
          <rules>
            <rule>
              <element>CLASS</element>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>*Test</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <limits>
                <limit>
                  <counter>LINE</counter>
                  <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                  <minimum>80%</minimum>
                </limit>
              </limits>
            </rule>
          </rules>
```

means that line coverage should be at least 80% **for each class**.

```
return new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
      put(input, "");
    }
  };
```

**declares [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes)**, what is BTW visible in JaCoCo report - see first table row on screenshot below

[image: report]

Whereas

```
  final Map<String, String> defaultMap = new HashMap<>();
  defaultMap.put(input, "");
  return defaultMap;
```

doesn't declare any class.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your gradle build

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            all {
                jvmArgs '-noverify'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is an issue with tests and coverage, so you need to configure `jvmArgs` setting for coverage check, it could be enabled in IDE itself, but when running coverage in CI/maven/wherever it should be configured in gradle